# Nexus 5: Different home screen with lockscreen enabled vs disabled? Huh?

Tags: nexus-5

community:

I am a new Android user, and I've spent most of the weekend banging around on my Nexus 5 making it work the way I want. For the most part, I am super happy. But, I'm experiencing something weird that I can't find any documentation for, and I can't tell if it's expected behavior that I think is weird to me because I'm new to Android/Nexus 5, or if it's genuinely weird.

After I got the phone, I disabled the lockscreen. I didn't intend this to be permanent--I just did it so I could get to the home screen faster while I was installing new apps and setting up the home screen. (I think I'm using the right terminology -- "home screen" is the screen displayed after you turn on the phone, and displayed again any time you press the home button, right? Because, home button?)

After I got the home screens looking the way I want, I re-enabled the lock screen with a swipe to open. With the lock screen enabled, after I swipe and then dismiss the Google search screen, I don't get my nicely configured home screen that I spent several hours on -- I see the original home screen that came with the phone, with most of my apps not available. When I click Home, I get my "good" home screen, and I can't get the old weird one to show up again until I turn off the screen. Then, when I turn on the screen and swipe and dismiss the Google search, I'm back to weird unupdated home page.

When I turn the lock screen off entirely, the correct home screen is immediately displayed when I press the power button.

I was willing to shrug my shoulders and say "Android is weird, I'll just set up this weird post-swipe homescreen to look exactly the way I want, and then it won't matter," BUT not all of my apps are in the app list to add to this weird unconfigured home screen that shows up after I swipe away the lock screen.

So, to get to the home screen I want, I have to swipe the lock screen, dismiss the Google voice/search prompt, and then press the Home button, which shows the good home screen, and there's no access to the bad home screen until I press the power button off, then on, then swipe again.

Attached please find screen shots of:
* The first thing I see if the lock screen is disabled---this is the desired home screen
* The first screen I see if the lock screen is enabled (after I swipe away lock screen and dismiss Google prompt)

Can anyone shed some light on this for me? I really appreciate the help and I thank you in advance for assisting a newbie.

Regards,
Elissa M.

Comment: When you're on your home screen, your good one, how many times do you have to swipe left to get to the Google Now page?

Comment: It would really help if you add the screenshots you describe, and one of the "Google search screen" that shows up after the lock screen.

Comment: I have seen this same behaviour when installing a 3rd party "home screen" or sometimes called "launcher". For a long time in one android device I had basically 2 home screens, the original and the 3rd party one which was much better. I could set which is default, and still could get back to the original.  Could this be what your observing?